# How to conditional format one cell where compared to a value of another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have one excel sheet with the following structure

```
productcode,name
```

I have another sheet with

```
productcode, name, availability
```

I am trying to check the availability of productcode from sheet1 if it is equal to productcode in sheet2 to make productcode from sheet1 green if it is available or red if it is not.

How can I make it?
thank you

Comment: See [How to Use Formulas in Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f).

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, Maria. I can think of a couple ways to do this, but would need more info. Is your availability sheet an inventory? Or, does the availability column just state "Available" or "Unavailable"? Can you edit your question to provide more detail and possibly an example of how your data is set up?

Comment: It says available or unavailable