# Cannot lookup value and create conditional formatting in excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting, vlookup

I have one worksheet which has in the A column product sku and at C D E  columns supplier names.

Each supplier has its own worksheet which has again product sku price and availability.(suppliers have variable number of product sku)

I want in the initial worksheet to make green or red the name of supplier based on the sku and by looking the supplier worksheet.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser! Head over to the [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/help/asking) page to get some handy hints on how to ask the best possible question for your issue. Might help the people answering your question if you could post a screenshot of how your worksheet layout/supplier worksheet layout with an edit of your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditional format one cell where compared to a value of another sheet](https://superuser.com/questions/1309400/how-to-conditional-format-one-cell-where-compared-to-a-value-of-another-sheet)